# .dbf assocaited with aerial photos

Tags: qgis

I have aerial photos that are .jp2 format and are compiled into a .dbf. In ArcGIS I can simple add the .dbf file and all the aerials automatically appear. Can this be done in QGIS, rather than insert each individual .jp2 file?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you referring to using a raster catalog in ArcGIS? http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/raster%20catalog

Comment: Yes, I believe that I am. I did find how to build a virtual raster, but if there are missing tiles its colored black.